# Fresh install of windows 7 "frozen" logo at "starting windows"

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, freeze

I have been trying to install and boot a windows 7 on my laptop which has UEFI.

When I boot, the "starting windows" animation plays for a short while (like only small colorful dots are just present" and then the animation freezes. no matter how much I wait, it doesn't load.

Its a brand new fresh install of windows 7 and I already have searched about it, and got absolutely no result. tried several different windows iso and yet no luck.

My PC has no hardware problems as it runs win 10 perfectly and boots under 5 seconds.

I have tried using safe mode, startup repair, anythings else. tried with both GPT and MBR schemes, both with CSM-mode on, and off. my cpu is a Intel 7700k and gtx 1050 gpu.

My hard drive is not removable.

I would also like to back up my data before doing anything else, any suggestions on how to do this when it no longer boots.

I have checked my RAM and its fine. and i cant open my laptop to change some components or plug out the GPU as some people have suggested over the net. If anyone knows what should i do to fix the problem i would be thankful and would also help many other users who seem to have the same problem but have no luck at finding their answer over the net.

Comment: So Windows 7 installed but will not boot into Windows after installation?

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode? Older Windows 7 was BIOS and had to be copied to flash drive & files moved to /EFI/Boot to allow UEFI boot. Newer Windows 7 should boot in UEFI mode, but you have to choose in UEFI boot menu. Backup Windows 10 versions of boot files in ESP.

Comment: @Moab no it wont.

Comment: @oldfred as i said i tried with csm on and also with csm off, and yes i tried the newer windows 7 iso files. what do you mean by backup of windows 10 boot files in ESP?

Comment: It could be how you made the bootable usb for installation, how did you do this?

Comment: You absolutely do not want CSM on. If you force that install it converts gpt drive to MBR and erases entire hard drive. Windows only boots in UEFI from gpt and only in BIOS/CSM from MBR.  Windows may not show the ESP, you typically have to mount it. But best to have that backed up as many tools do not back that up also.

Comment: In order to backup your data you may use a third party Windows 10 rescue disk or Live Linux Distro to do a Live USB/CD/DVD booting on your laptop (Assuming Windows 10 or Live Linux does not freeze at boot logo) and connecting external mass storage devices to backup your current data.

Comment: You have not mentioned the model of laptop and when was it manufactured. However generally almost all laptops designed starting 2016 are designed with UEFI Firmware and Windows 10 in mind. As a result they incorporate UEFI GOP (Graphics Output Protocol) for which Windows 7 does not have any native driver support. So BSOD/Hang/Crash or may be a red bar at top on screen may be encountered with Windows 7. Attempt to boot and install Windows 7 on such laptops is with CSM Mode ON. ...Continued.

Comment: If there’s any explicit switch called OS Support (Options like Windows 10/Other/Linux etc) in Firmware setup try setting it to Other OS, set CSM On and retry. If you can access the UEFI Firmware settings (Traditionally still being called as BIOS by many) try to upgrade the BIOS to any latest version and retry. Did you install Windows 7 with UEFI Mode on at the time of installation?

Answer (score 1):

When that happens on my PC, it means it's overheating, and the CPU throttled all the way down, to a stop.

When you clean install Windows, the files on your removable medium are copied onto the RAM, then decompressed on the hard drive. That calls for a lot of load on the CPU and bus, and sometimes leads to overheating. Maybe some setting in the BIOS could help you reduce that strain and proceed with the install?